# Subgroup of intersection of clopen sets gets smaller and smaller

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, topological-groups

Given a topological group $G$ we can define $G_1$ to be the subgroup given by the intersection of all clopen sets containing the neutral element. For $n>1$ we define recursively  $G_n:=(G_{n-1})_1$.

Now I'm looking for a group $G$ such that $G_n \ne G_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Is there an easy example?

By the way: We have $G_n = G_{n+1}$ iff $G_n$ is the connected component of the neutral element in $G$.

Comment: Do you assume that $G$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Nope. Is it impossible for Hausdorff groups or why are you asking?

Comment: The question immediately reduces to the Hausdorff case by modding out by the closure of $\{1_G\}$, since the latter is contained in $G_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Would you already give an example for which $G_1\neq G_2$ (i.e., in which $G_1$ is not connected)?

Comment: @YCor Such an examle would already be neat. But I'd prefer $G_2 \ne G_3$.

Comment: I guess MathOverflow would be the right place for such a question (I suggest to include Hausdorff in the assumption, since it's no restriction and the only really interesting case).